# How can I create a corresponding struct containing mpfr.h types using ctypes in python?

Tags: python, c, struct, ctypes, mpfr

I have a C API with functions that work on the following C struct:

```
typedef struct s_t{
    mpq_ptr mpq;
    mpfr_ptr mpfr;
} s_t;
```

I am building a python wrapper for this C API, so I need to define this struct as a class that inherits from the 'Structure' class in ctypes and then give value to _field_. However mpq_ptr, mpfr_ptr are types from mpfr.h and there are no corresponding ctypes types for them. Is there a way to solve this problem?

What I want to obtain in python is something like:

```
class S_t(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('mpq', CTYPEFOR(mpq_ptr)),('mpfr', CTYPEFOR(mpfr_ptr))]
```

So that I can create such objects in python and pass them to the corresponding C functions that take s_t as an input argument.

Comment: Do you *need* the types `mpq` or `mprf`?! if they're *opaque* types, then know that *any* pointer to struct would do there - all struct pointers are guaranteed to have the same presentation. If not, then you *need* to create the definition for `mpq` and `mpfr` naturally.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I need them both. And I am also interested about the general case... Is there a way to load some types from a c shared library, use them as such in python and then pass them to a c function that is loaded from a different c shared library?

Comment: The shared library *doesn't* have the types; only the header file (i.e. `mpfr.h`) has them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by tracking all the typedefs in the mpfr.h and gmp.h files and creating all necessary structs in python as:

```
class Mpz(Structure):
     # define struct manually

class Mpq(Structure):
     # define struct manually

class Mpfr(Structure):
     # define struct manually
```